# rvm init.d script

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, init.d

I currentyl have ruby 1.8.7 setup with rvm.  Currently everything is working with rvmsudo, however I need an init.d script that can run the following:
rvmsudo /var/rails/sandbox/script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox

unfortunately the rvmsudo part is making it difficult since root does not recongize rvmsudo.  does anyone have any ideas on how I can write this init script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use full path to it: `/path/to/rvm/bin/rvmsudo`

Comment: ok I did that thanks, I am just running in an issue now where its using up my terminal, basically if i kill my ssh session it dies off.    I have 2 scripts, my init script is : su -c /files/sandbox and /files/sandbox is: cd /var/rails/sandbox/
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p358@server/ruby /var/rails/sandbox/script/server -p 8080 -e sandbox
basically my init script will not run in the background with this and I am forced to only be able to run it at the actual console, any ideas on how to get this to run in the background?